# How to check key state Down/Up/Hold in Gvim?

Tags: key-bindings, gvim

A while ago, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26680775/12349101) answer, and thought if this was possible in Gvim somehow.

I'm only curious in knowing how to `know` the key state of a particular key, or at least the 3 main ones: Down, Up, and Hold. I already know how to press key in vimscript (either using `feedkeys` and :keyhere so this is irrelevant)

While I know it might be non-implemented in terminal's version of `vim` (eg: without additonal patch, etc) is it also the case for `gvim`?

P.S.:I'm using version 8.1.

Comment: This isn't possible even in gvim.

Comment: I don't think that vim exposes any kind of keyboard API besides `input()`, sending keys, and mappings. However, you could probably write a systems-level program in (say), C, Rust, Racket, etc., and then call out to that or set it up as a job and communicate with it.

Comment: Yeah, I already planned making a system level thing for this (can do this easily in python using Xlib since other modules that do this seems to have a couple bugs in my own experience) but I still asked this since I wanted, as you already know, a vimscript or ready made solution in vim/gvim :) @D.BenKnoble

Comment: To quote Ingo's answer `I'd recommend to rather re-think your approach; there's certainly a different way.`. That does sound like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) maybe you should explain what you really want to achieve and we can help you find an alternative solution easier than implementing system-level programs.

Comment: this isn't really a XY problem, as I planned to use the answer to this question for a couple of my own needs. That aside, I believe it's obvious that I want to make keybinding or vimscript that does *something* specific based on the key state (down, up, hold) of certain mapping/keys :) @statox

Comment: "I believe it's obvious that I want to make keybinding or vimscript that does something specific based on the key state" that's precisely my point, I don't know what you want to do exactly but I'd be surprised that you can't achieve your end goal in a different way. But of course I could be completely wrong :)

Comment: yes, and I appreciate that :D Mind you, what I said earlier is the *literal goal* here (eg: there no other underlying goal beside that). To make this clearer, I guess I could say this is to make a new keymapping scheme different from the default one in gvim/vim but the one I have in mind require to know if it's pressed down, up or hold down... @statox

Comment: That's why it's interesting to discuss: If you want to dig more on this alternative keymapping scheme you might be interested in [vim-submodes](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2467) this is an old plugin (it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore but when I used it 5 or 6 years ago it didn't really had bugs I think) it allows you to create "additional modes" that you switch into with a defined mapping and you can configure new mapping active only in these new modes. That might be the kind of code you want to look at to explore you idea :)

Comment: that's *actually* another different thing I wanted to do, and planned to either ask a question about it or make it myself (ended up making it myself and picked up more experience in using vimscript). Thanks a lot, I didn't know this was already a thing (searched around without finding this) @statox

Comment: btw, thanks to your help previously, I ended up finding a really close solution to what I want (by the same author) called [vim-arpeggio](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425) although this only work for simultaneous pressed key, it at least does one of the thing I wanted to do with my previously explained keymapping scheme :D Thanks! @statox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find an *exact* solution to this, but I did find something close: [vim-arpeggio](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425).

It only handles *simultaneously pressed keys* so I'll take that as doing half of what I wanted.

A full solution would either require adding the rest of the feature to this plugin or another or using a system-wide key event detector, which isn't too hard to make (for the latter, not the former).

EDIT 1:

After some time and looking back on the SO post in my question, I noticed the comment mentioned `getchar` and `getcharmod`. Thanks to this, I found [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Wait_for_user_input_(getchar)_without_moving_cursor), which seems like it could be a good basis for what I want too (or at least an alternative).

Comment: Wow, that plugin is really really cool